# getOffice365ActiveUserDetail with period parameter no longer working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Starting the night of August 30th, the REST API endpoint: [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getOffice365ActiveUserDetail(period='D30')](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getOffice365ActiveUserDetail(period=%27D30%27)) is no longer working.  Tried all the different options for period value (D7,D90,D180).  This endpoint has been working without issue for as long as we've been using it (going back almost 2 years)

By no longer working, the status_code being returned is 200 - and the csv is being returned with column headers, but **no user data is included**.

Note that using the date parameter is working as expected (returning column headers and data):
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getOffice365ActiveUserDetail(date=2021-08-10)

Does anyone have any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue should be fixed. Check [these recent changes](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/changes-to-the-microsoft-365-usage-reports-api/). Note that there is also changes in user anonymity that masks user identifying data by default, you can learn more about on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69070987/getsharepointsiteusagedetail-in-microsoft-graph-api-returns-garbage/69071411#69071411) and on [Privacy changes to Microsoft 365 Usage Analytics](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-blog/privacy-changes-to-microsoft-365-usage-analytics/ba-p/2694137).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to alert MO282045:

> Title: Admins may see no data for specific reports after August 31,
> 2021
>
> User Impact: Admins may see no data for specific reports after August
> 31, 2021.
>
> More info: Impacted reports (both admin center usage reports and when
> requesting via Graph API) include:
>
> -OneDrive Activity Report.
> -OneDrive Site Usage Report.
> -SharePoint Activity Report.
> -SharePoint Site Usage Report.
> -ProplusUsage Report.
> -Forms Report.
> -FormPro Report.
> -LicenseActivity Report (also known as Active User Usage Report).
> -MultiGeo Report.
> -Power BI Report.
> -Exchange Activity Report.
> -Email Activity Report.
>
> Current status: We've identified an upstream data issue associated
> with loading tenant profile and usage report data. We're developing on
> a fix to remediate impact.
>
> Scope of impact: This issue may impact admins running any of the
> listed reports from August 31, 2021.
>
> Root cause: An upstream data issue associated with loading tenant
> profile and usage report data, is providing unexpected results for
> specific reports.
>
> Next update by: Thursday, September 2, 2021, 11:00 AM (9:00 AM UTC)

**EDIT**:
It also might be related to this planned change:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-ww/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=81959

> User level information contained in Microsoft 365 reports in the Admin center will be pseudonymized by default. Global administrators can revert this change for their tenant, which will be an audited event. When user identification is enabled, administrative roles and the report reader role will be able to see identifiable user level information. Global reader and Usage Summary Reports Reader roles will not have access to identifiable user information, regardless of the setting chosen.