# getSharePointSiteUsageDetail in Microsoft Graph API returns garbage

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I have been using GET /reports/getSharePointSiteUsageDetail(period='D7') to successfully retreive Sharepoint statistics from Sharepoint Online (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getsharepointsiteusagedetail?view=graph-rest-1.0).

Now instead of different useful column values ("Site Id", "Site URL")... there are strange GUIDs in the most output:

> 

"Site Id": "7DF42FE5807C478D141F3DD20E1ED98D" (this is not a site id)

> 

"Site DisplayName": empty

> 

"Owner Display Name": EAA87B4F54D5DEB1884C0CB1BE0A64C7 (there should be a display name)

> 

"Last Activity Date": "2021-02-08" (is OK)

> 

"Owner Principal Name": "01153FE8A3CAFDF5F3DDB2CAD9DE8AD0" (there should be a UPN)

> 

Were there unannounced changes in Microsoft Graph API that broke everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of [Privacy changes to Microsoft 365 Usage Analytics](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-blog/privacy-changes-to-microsoft-365-usage-analytics/ba-p/2694137). You need to disable the anonymize user data feature. follow the screenshot below from [Admin Portal](https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/Home#/Settings/Services/:/Settings/L1/Reports)

[image]