# Not getting response in ms graph reports api using graph explorer

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to call below api with global admin user
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getSharePointActivityUserDetail(period='D7')`
but getting below error in ms graph explorer.
I also tried other apis related to reports but all have same result as below.

[image: Response]

Can you please tell me what went wrong here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a Graph API problem. The endpoint returns CSV data that Graph Explorer will parse and fail.

Try this on postman which will render the CSV data correctly.

[image]

Note that the user specific data is hidden by default. To expose them follow this [getSharePointSiteUsageDetail in Microsoft Graph API returns garbage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69070987/getsharepointsiteusagedetail-in-microsoft-graph-api-returns-garbage/69071411#69071411)